# Cakephp user management plugin create tables

Tags: mysql, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0, user-management

I'm having a small issue. I'm trying to install a plugin (http://plugins.cakephp.org/p/720-users), the user management plugin. For this, I need to create some mysql tables, but I guess you need to create these via a php file and the Console of cakephp. The problem is that I have a very simple server that can only run php and a mysql database. Is there a way to create the sql code out of this php file without the console? The file is question is https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Confi

Comment: please can you share your code.

Comment: This is the code: https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Config/Schema/schema.php @vikramsharma

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Get a less crappy host. I'm paying only $12 for 3 month (!) for my private virtual server with root access.

Alternatively you could run the migration or schema shell locally, dump the tables and insert them via phpmyadmin on your crappy host.